# Convert string to list by special symbol including this symbol, miss double symbols (as escaped character)

Tags: python, regex, string, list

Sorry, if I repeat question, but still...

String contain a lot of symbols, caret ('^') is a delimiter:

```
string = "^h^c^04^^^13/     \^d^b  /   \^u^u^u^u^u^u^u^l^l\^o^b^r/"`
```

As result I need took list in format:

```
result = ['^h', '^c', '^04', '^^', '^13/     \' ... etc..]
```

I tried use `re.split("(?!\^{2})(\^)"` but this return data in format:

```
['', '^', 'h', '^', 'c', '^', '04^^', '^', '13/ \\', '^', 'd', '^', 'b  /   \\', ...]
```

Can anyone suggest how to get data in appropriate format? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> string = "^h^c^04^^^13/     \^d^b  /   \^u^u^u^u^u^u^u^l^l\^o^b^r/"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\^.+?(?=\^|$)', string)
['^h', '^c', '^04', '^^', '^13/     \\', '^d', '^b  /   \\', '^u', '^u', '^u',
 '^u', '^u', '^u', '^u', '^l', '^l\\', '^o', '^b', '^r/']
```

used non-greedy match (`.+?`) to match as little as possible.

and postive look-ahead assertion (`(?=...)`) to make the pattern match till next `^` or the end of the string (`$`).